# How to allow content editors to choose from Image Styles during content creation?

Tags: media, nodes

Say I have an image field and several different Image Styles (image cache presets) set up. I would like to allow my content editors to be able to choose from the list of available presets during content creation.

Any Ideas on this is achieved? Off the top of my head it seems like a custom module might be in order...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily enough there's already a module that does exactly this, [Formatter Field](http://drupal.org/project/formatter_field). The example use case given on the module page is exactly the same as yours:

> The formatter field module provides a mechanism for specifying a formatter and formatter settings to be used for displaying a field, on a per-entity basis. By default, Drupal provides formatters and settings per entity bundle, but in certain situations it is necessary to choose the formatter at the entity level.
>
> For example, say you have a page node with an image field. Normally, you would select an image style as the formatter, and all page nodes would use that same image style. With this module, you can add a formatter field to page nodes, which is hooked up to the image field. Then when the node is created or edited, the image style can be selected per-node.

Comment: super. clive to the rescue once again.